# Creating a matrix without using for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to generate a `n*n` matrix in MATLAB, where each entry is `A(i,j) = j^i`, `i=j=1...n` but without using a for loop. In the MATLAB help, I saw a function `matrix(m,n,f)`, but I don't know how to use that one.

Comment: Please provide a sample output to make clear what you are after.  What is `i=j=n` in your equation?

Comment: I think the poster means `i=j=1...n`.

Comment: Or rather `i,j = 1...n`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
A = bsxfun(@power, 1:n, (1:n).');
```

Comment: Thanks!by the way, what's the meaning of (1:n).' ？

Comment: @Joey Cheng - See `help punct` for an interesting description of the punctuation operators in MATLAB.  This is the non-conjugate transpose.

Comment: @JoeyCheng It is a column vector from 1 to n. You should read `help punct` as @chappjc says, it is very useful

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
[A,b]=meshgrid(1:n);
M=A.^b;
```

Comment: not exactly, I want every entry Aij to be j^i, so if n = 3, I will get [1,2,3;1,4,9;1,8,27], and can you explain the mechanisms behind the equation, by which I mean the meaning of the (1:n) the ' and the * means? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoeyCheng  Please edit your question to include this information, instead of placing it in the comments.  You can do this by clicking the "edit" button under your post.

Comment: @nispio I think his question is alright (apart from the i=j=n part). I had initially misread it as each element being i*j not i^j. It was my mistake.

Comment: Thanks so much David, but can you briefly explain what is the meaning of meshgrid(1:n) and A.^b?

Comment: Sure. Meshgrid [link](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) takes two vectors and constructs two matrices which give all the combinations of the input vectors. In this case, the input vector is `1:n` which is the vector `[1 2 3 4 5 ... n]`. So you get two matrices like `[1 1 1;2 2 2;3 3 3]` and `[1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3]`. Then the `A.^b` is taking each element of `A` and raising it to the power of the corresponding element in `b` [link](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/power.html). Hope that helps.